# carousel in Bootstrap 4 not functioning with correct div tags and code

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I've seen several questions asked with similar topics and none of those got resolved, or addressed my issue.
I've got the div tags added as such:

```
  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="2000" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/deals-steals1.png" width="488" height="232" class="d-block w-100" 
         alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="images/deals-steals1a.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="images/deals-steals1b.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

At the top in my head tags I have my needed CSS files.

And at the bottom I have various js includes, right before the closing body tag. I am running a BS modal as well in the page, but it shouldn't interfere. I also theoretically have the needed jQuery file

```
    <!-- jQuery plugins-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script><br>


 <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any help or pointers you guys can provide would be great.

Comment: Usually when this happened to me either jquery was not getting loaded or was loading after the bootstrap.js file. Check the network tab in your browser to see if jquery is giving a 404 response or getting loaded after the boostrap file. I would also check the browser console to see if you see an error saying something like "jquery is not loaded"

Comment: it looks like you are loading jquery twice. once here `js/jquery.min.js` then again here `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Good point on that extra jquery.min reference. I had removed it while testing and I still got no errors but it wouldn't work. I neglected to mention and add that I also had a jQuery function up top, in the head tags:
function fireCarousel(){
    $('#mycarousel').carousel(fireCarousel);
}  But despite that it was not working.

Comment: I am seeing this, but I'm not sure if or that it explicitly deals with the carousel app...
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
    at c.slide (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at c.next (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at f (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Well, this is very strange. I created a new HTML Bootstrap template file in DreamWeaver to test. It kind of works. By that I mean, if I preview and inspect the element and go to the  carousel-inner element, it will start rotating right before my eyes. This seems very hit and miss, though, in regards to size, and what kind of divs are already present. For example the other file shows the images stacked and they never will rotate at all. The one that somewhat works shows the active image and hides the other two.